# Query about function overloading

Tags: c++, function, overloading, literals

When using function with same name, parameter list must differ(either in type of parameter or number of parameters used). I was just practicing with this concept. I wrote the following code.

```
   #include <iostream> 
    int myFunction(int n)
   { 
    return 2*n;
   }
    float myFunction(float n)
   { 
    return 3*n;
   }
    int main()
   {
    int x=myFunction(3);
    std::cout << x; 
    return 0;
   }
```

I thought I will get error because compiler will get confused which myFunction to use because I directly pass the value 3 without storing it in a particular type of variable . But I got output 6. So I tried the following code.

```
   #include <iostream> 
    int myFunction(int n)
   { 
    return 2*n;
   }
    float myFunction(float n)
   { 
    return 3*n;
   }
    int main()
   {
    float x=myFunction(3.3);
    std::cout << x; 
    return 0;
   }
```

As previous one worked fine, I thought this will work fine too, as 3.3 is not integer so it's clear which one to call, but this time I got compiler error saying it's ambiguous.

So my doubt is why first code worked but not second one.

Comment: `3` has type `int` (you don't have to store it in a variable to give it a type), and there is a perfect match for it. `3.3` has type `double`, and both `int` and `float` are candidates. Try `3.3f` instead. Or `3u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literals have types too. As [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) `3` is of type `int`, then the 1st overload is selected.

As [floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) `3.3` is of type `double` (but not `float`; with the suffix `f` like `3.3f` the type is determined as `float`), the calling is ambiguous because it could convert to both `int` and `float` implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The process of selecting the overload during a call is called [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). Given the types of the arguments, the compiler selects the [best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) from the list of candidates - the one that can be invoked with the least amount of promotions and implicit conversions.

In the first case the first one `myFunction(int)` requires 0 conversions for an `int` argument (`3`), and the second one requires one conversion (`int` -> `float`), so the first one is selected as the best candidate.

In the second case a `double` argument (`3.3`) requires a conversion to either `int` or `float`, so there is no clear winner and thus the call is ambiguous.

The fix could be to use a `float` argument (`3.3f`) or change `myFunction(float)` to `myFunction(double)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int x=myFunction(int(3));

float x=myFunction(float(3.3));
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.